# How to program in another language contr() scilab function

Tags: scilab

how are you?.

I'm trying to program the contr() scilab function what if I understand well it finds an orthogonal staircase controlable form of a linear multi-input system of the form

```
dx(t)/dt = A*x(t) + B*u(t)
```

at Scilab's help it says that is based in AB01ND routine and in the documentation for that routine found in the following link [AB01ND](http://slicot.org/objects/software/shared/doc/AB01ND.html) is the source code to obtain the controllable orthogonal staircase form needed.

I don't know what language is that and I need to know which language is that to translate the AB01ND code  and write it to wxMaxima's pseudo code. Can someone help me with that?, at least saying to me what language it is and its reference can be found easily.

Another question that I have is if that code (AB01ND) is all I need to program in wxMaxima the contr() function or it is wrapped inside another piece of code.

Of course I have to say that I didn't found the contr.sci in Scilab's program directory, only a .tst file which calls internally the contr() function.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: AB01ND is written in Fortran and is part of slicot library (http://slicot.org/). The algorithm used is detailed here (http://slicot.org/objects/software/shared/doc/AB01ND.html). What you will need is something computing a rank-revealing QR factorization.

Comment: Thanks @Stéphane Mottelet, knowing that is Fortran I can advance from there.

Comment: I think that you can use Lapack in WxMaxima, hence QR factorization would not be a big deal.